# Filter with ComboBox and TextBox in C # SqlServer

Tags: c#, sql-server, desktop-application

I have to filter the data of a datagrid with a textview and a combo box. But, the following happens: the combo initializes to 0 so it doesn't capture the value of the first item. Try adding an item manually so that the value 0 is "Select" and the others are from the database.

Error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The Items collection cannot be modified
>   when the DataSource property is set.'

In the following method I try to formulate the sql query to take the parameters (combobox and textbox) and perform the filter in the datagrid:

```
private void filtrarTituloYAEMP(int valor)
{
   cmbTipoPago.Items.Add("Seleccione");
   if (txtTitulo.Text == null || txtTitulo.Text == "")
   {
       try
       {
          llenaTitulo();
       }
       catch (SqlException ex)
       {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
       }
   }
   else
   {
       try
       {
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection();
            conexion.ConnectionString = "acá mi conexión a la bd";
            conexion.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            string sSQL = "SELECT titulo FROM V_CuetaWeb, ArchivoElectronico_MedioPago where titulo LIKE @valor + '%' and AEMP_Id = @id";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sSQL, conexion);
            command.Parameters.Add("@valor", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = valor;
            command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbTipoPago.SelectedValue);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            da.Fill(ds, "V_CuetaWeb");
            conexion.Close();
            dtgTitulo.DataSource = ds;
            dtgTitulo.DataMember = "V_CuetaWeb";
        }
        catch (SqlException exx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exx.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly, it doesn't work that way. So, the problems are:

1- That the ComboBox has an extra option ('Select') that takes the value 0

2- That the method filter with the textbox and the combobox

Does anyone have any idea how to fix those details?

Comment: As explained by the error message you can't add to the Items collection when the DataSource property is set. Instead get the table from the DataSet and add that line directly to the table

Comment: Also, you should really start to use the JOIN syntax in sql and forget about the old way to express the relationship between tables: [Bad habits to kick: using old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to get this to work is to modify your Select statement from:

```
    string sSQL = "SELECT titulo FROM V_CuetaWeb, ArchivoElectronico_MedioPago where titulo LIKE @valor + '%' and AEMP_Id = @id";
```

to

```
    string sSQL = "select 'Seleccione' union SELECT titulo FROM V_CuetaWeb, ArchivoElectronico_MedioPago where titulo LIKE @valor + '%' and AEMP_Id = @id";
```

You could also insert a new DataRow at position 0 into your result DataTable once the query has been run and filled by the DataAdapter.

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(new DataRow("Seleccione"]),0);
```

Comment: The line: ```ds.Tables[0].Rows.InsertAt(new DataRow("Seleccione"),0); it doesn't works to me```

Error: 
```datarow does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments```